# MySQL Daemon failed to start Linux

Tags: mysql

I have googled a lot about this issue though there are some solution available however I tried all of them and seems that my issue is slightly different. 
Can someone pls help me resolve this.

OS: OEL6.5 Linux
MySQL 5.5

```
MySQL.log:
180625 12:03:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180625 12:03:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180625 12:03:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180625 12:03:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
180625 12:03:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 15.0G
180625 12:03:52 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180625 12:03:52 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
180625 12:03:52  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Error: trying to add tablespace 2113 of name './items_table.ibd'
InnoDB: to the tablespace memory cache, but tablespace
InnoDB: 2113 of name './customer_table.ibd' already exists in the tablespace
InnoDB: memory cache!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important:**
Before starting to play with db files make a dump (mysqldump -A > mydb.sql).

Consider following one of the options below:

1. Moving `items_table.ibd` out from the directory tree and restarting mysql will fix the Error.
2. Recreate MySQL data dir: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103625/how-to-reinitialise-var-lib-mysql-files